# quick differential forms question

Tags: differential-forms

I know that for a 1-form A,

$$
dA=-Ad
$$

where d is the exterior derivative (and in my expression on concern it will be acting on something else to the right no worries).

But what about 0-forms? Does the same hold?

$$
dU=-Ud
$$

for a 0-form U.

Comment: What you've written makes no sense. If what is missing is wedging with another form, certainly $d(A\wedge B) = dA\wedge B - A\wedge dB$, but how that makes sense from your equation is beyond me.  For functions $U$, $d(UB) = dU\wedge B + U\,dB$. (I have some suspicion you're thinking of this in the context of vector-valued forms, but still no idea what you actually meant by the question.)

Answer (score 0):

Ah, sorry, what is on the left does indeed matter.

Consider the identity from this 0-form U I had above,

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
U U^{-1} &=& 1 \\
d(U U^{-1}) &=& d(1) \\
d(U)U^{-1} + U (d U^{-1})&=& 0 \\
d(U)U^{-1} &=& - U (d U^{-1})
\end{eqnarray*}$$

This was my fault in only looking into the dA=-Ad applied to 0-forms without considering what the d now acts on to the right.

Comment: Does $U^{-1}$ even have to make sense?